# C# serial port communication returning different values in Pascal

Tags: c#, serial-port

i'm programming serial port communication with hardware by our supplier. It's trivial, but I cannot get the right data from the port. I need to write to serial port 2 bytes of address, then receive 1 byte confirmation. HW supplier has testing software, which works exactly like that, but when I write the same bytes, then what I get from it is different.

How should it look like:

```
Write: 0x00 0x01
Read: 0xAA
```

How I get results:

```
Write: 0x00 0x01
Read: 0x3F 0x3F 0xAA - sometimes just 0x3F one time
```

I'm using SerialPort class in C#. Testing software from HW supplier is written is Pascal(synaser library) - I do not have source code. It seems like C# is doing something more behind, but I cannot find the issue. For data analysis I used Free Device Monitoring Studio to analyze exact data on the bus.

```
        private bool SendAddress()
        {
            int confirmation;
            byte[] address = { (byte)((Address >> 8) & 0xFFu), Address };
            var confirmed = false;
            var port = new SerialPort(Port, 19200, Parity.Mark, 8);

            port.WriteTimeout = 200;
            port.ReadTimeout = 200;

            StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Opening port for address.");
            port.Open();
            StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Port opened.");
            StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Discarding buffers.");
            port.DiscardOutBuffer();
            port.DiscardInBuffer();
            StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Buffers discarded.");
            StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Writing address: " + BitConverter.ToString(address));
            //port.Write(address, 0, address.Length);
            port.BaseStream.WriteByte(0x00);
            port.BaseStream.WriteByte(0x01);
            StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Address written.");

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Waiting for confirmation.");
                    confirmation = port.ReadByte();
                    StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Confirmation value received: " + BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(confirmation), 0, 1));

                    if (confirmation == 0xAA)
                    {
                        StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Confirmed.");
                        confirmed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Invalid confirmation value.");
                    }
                }
            } catch(TimeoutException)
            {
                port.Close();
                throw;
            }

            StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Closing port.");
            port.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();

            if (confirmed == false)
            {
                StatusReaderService.PortLoggers[Port].Debug(Name + " Confirmation not received.");
                return confirmed;
            }

            return confirmed;
        }
```

I'm looping through the result, but thats not the way we want to do it. Didn't someone experience similar problem?

Comment: Does 0x3F have semantics in the supplier's protocol? Could it be the case that the testing software simply discards 0x3F?

Comment: Btw: Why not `port.Close();` in a `finally` block?

Comment: There is no value 0x3F in suppliers protocol - they checked it. I have the values from serial port monitor, so there must be something hidden in C#, which is causing these value mismatches. Finally is good point, I'm new in C#.

Comment: I am not sure if it _could_ be residue from former communication. Have you tried to purge the input buffer before writing ouput? Then read from a clean input buffer?

Comment: Yes I do this after every port opening.

Comment: Maybe also check for some of the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbyte?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks) on `ReadByte`

Comment: AH, yes, just saw you are doing discards ... hm ...

Comment: I read that section, but I dunno how to understand that. I'm only reading and writing bytes, not switching between chars and bytes :-/

Comment: For example, is the parity setting wrong and the [SerialPort.ParityReplace Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.parity?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) is set to`?`?

Comment: You are absolutely right! ParityReplace is 0x3F. Didn't notice that. According to my call with HW supplier, it expects 9th bit 1 on writing instructions, but then it doesn't send data with parity. How do I deal with this? Ignore that value as I do for now?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for help. [kunif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014308/kunif) revealed the problem.

HW supplier told me that it's receiving address with parity set to 1, but then sends confirmation without parity. It's suppliers problem as it should return data with same parity. So SerialPort class replaced errors with it's defined 0x3F value. In suppliers SW, where Pascal is used, there is no parity check.

Didn't notice that since C# didn't throw any exception and it's my first real experience with serial port.

One more time thanks all :)